# How do I create an XML template in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, templates

The XML file I need to create is like

```
<file>
     <state>$state</state>
     <timestamp>$time</timestamp>
     <location>$location</location>
          ....
</file>
```

I don't want to use several print to create the needed XML file, what I'm expecting is to have a template, which defines both the structure and format of the XML.

Then when create the XML file, I just need to  provide the actually values for the variables in the template and write the specified template to a newly created file once, only once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`HTML::Template`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Template;

my $template_text = <<EO_TMPL;
<TMPL_LOOP FILES>
<file>
     <state><TMPL_VAR STATE></state>
     <timestamp><TMPL_VAR TIME></timestamp>
     <location><TMPL_VAR LOCATION></location>
</file>
</TMPL_LOOP>
EO_TMPL

my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new( scalarref => \$template_text );

$tmpl->param(
    FILES => [
    { state => 'one', time => 'two', location => 'three' },
    { state => 'alpha', time => 'beta', location => 'gamma' },
]);

print $tmpl->output;
```

Output:

```
<file>
     <state>one</state>
     <timestamp>two</timestamp>
     <location>three</location>
</file>

<file>
     <state>alpha</state>
     <timestamp>beta</timestamp>
     <location>gamma</location>
</file>
```

Comment: The answer is exactly what I need .

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Template::Toolkit`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod) to do that

Answer (score 1):

[`cpan`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML&mode=module) has several XML modules you could use.

My suggestion is that you start with [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm) or [`XML::API`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-API/lib/XML/API.pm)