# Perl simple XML template from core modules only?

Tags: xml, perl

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1305749/719016), I would like to know what would be the best way to fill in an simple XML template in Perl using only core modules - I cannot use extra modules in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something very simple by using the substitute `s///` operator with the eval evaluate `/ee` modifier.

Something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template = <<'END';
<file>
     <state>$state</state>
     <timestamp>$time</timestamp>
     <location>$location</location>
</file>
END

my $state    = 'Oregon';
my $time     = '10:04';
my $location = 'Salem';

(my $output = $template) =~ s{(\$\w+)}{ $1 }eeg;

print $output;
```

**output**

```
<file>
     <state>Oregon</state>
     <timestamp>10:04</timestamp>
     <location>Salem</location>
</file>
```

Comment: Wow! That's simple and beautiful. I will read more about `/ee` now that I see how powerful it can be.

Comment: @200508519211022689616937: It's something that you *must* be very careful with, as calling `eval` on a string could cause untold damage. It is safe in this case because the string being evaluated is always the name of a scalar variable, and all `eval` can do is return that variable's contents. But there is nothing to prevent a string from containing a whole Perl program that deletes files and generally plays havoc with the system. Be doubly careful if your string originated from outside the program, and could have been provided by a malicious user.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious corollary to Borodin's suggest solution is to just use a hash to initialize your data.  Given he protected you by limiting the LHS of your regex to word characters, this is functionally the same.  But using a hash is probably better practice since only those variables you want imported into the template will be.

Additionally, you'll get slightly better error messages using this method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template = <<'END';
<file>
     <state>$state</state>
     <timestamp>$time</timestamp>
     <location>$location</location>
</file>
END

my %data = (
    state    => 'Oregon',
    time     => '10:04',
    location => 'Salem',
);

(my $output = $template) =~ s{\$(\w+)}{
    $data{$1} // die "Variable '$1' from template not initialized"
}eg;

print $output;
```